# Is it possible to pass a variable parameter to a filter?

Tags: node.js, pug

I decided to make `json` filter for convenience (instead of using JSON.stringify every time), but there are 2 problems (questions):

1. How to pass a variable to a filter parameter or body?
2. Tried to use `:json= some_variable`, but it sends `[object Object]`, so, how to send objects in body?

Comment: Please show your code. What do you mean by a filter?

Comment: @Graham Why remove the `pug` tag? People wont know what a filter is in a node.js context.

Comment: It was a mistake, corrected.  I was about to edit this question for clarity but instead voted to close it as there's no code present either.

Comment: @Soviut [here](https://pugjs.org/language/filters.html)